# Is money from selling an investment property taxed at the marginal rate?

Tags: taxes, canada, real-estate, capital-gain

If I sell my condo (an investment property, not my primary residence) then I imagine I need to pay tax (provided I make a profit).

If I don't make profit, can I use the loss against my salary income to reduce my income taxes?

If I do make a profit, am I doomed to pay tax at the marginal tax rate? If I make a decent profit, I imagine the RRSP contribution room is not enough to keep all my profits in there.

Comment: Is this your primary residence? I didn't think Canada [levied tax](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/127/rsdnc/dspsng/menu-eng.html) on capital gains from the sale of primary residences.

Comment: No this is my investment property. My primary residence is a rental, which is cheaper than the rent of my condo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If this is an investment property, it is subject to capital gains tax rather than being taxed at your marginal tax rate. This is almost certainly better for you; capital gains are generally taxed at half your marginal tax rate.

MoneySense has [an article](http://www.moneysense.ca/columns/can-you-avoid-capital-gains-tax) that goes into substantially more detail, discussing the principal residence exemption (which does not apply here), and when exactly a house is considered an investment property.

Generally speaking, it will almost certainly be worth hiring an accountant here.

Comment: In Canada would any capital losses be carried forward to future income years for potential reductions to future capital gains rather than reduce income tax in that year?

Comment: @Victor Yes -- in Canada, capital losses can be carried forward indefinitely, as well as backwards three years.  [(source)](http://www.taxtips.ca/filing/capitallosses.htm)